# Table with many columns

Tags: mysql

Im designing a table to store restaurant data
Problem is too many data to store.
What im looking is best way to structure this
I want to avoid a table with bunch of column since it look like bad design(is it?)

Some fragments of the data:

-Restaurant Name
-Address
-City
-State
-Zip
-Country
-Neighborhood / Tag
-Cuisine
..
..
-Policy

Here is my approach to the problem:

**Option 1:**

Put all data into 1 table.

```
+---------+----------+----------+-------------------------+  
| res_id  | option1  | option2 | option3 | .. | option20  |  
+---------+----------+---------+---------+----+----------+  
|         |         |          |         |    |          |  
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Option 2**

Split data to multiple table

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------------------+  
| res_id  | option1  | option2 | option3 |  option4    |  
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+  
|         |         |          |         |            |  
+---------+---------+----------+---------+------------+  

+---------+----------+----------+----------------------+  
| res_id  | option5  | option5 | option6 |  option7    |  
+---------+----------+---------+---------+------------+  
|         |         |          |         |            |  
+---------+---------+----------+---------+------------+
```

**Option3**

Use many to many relationship

`restaurant`

```
+---------+----------+----------+  
| res_id  |   name   | location |  
+---------+----------+---------+  
|    1    |   blah   |  blah    |  
+---------+---------+----------+ 
|    2    |  blah   |  blah    |  
+---------+---------+----------+
```

`info`

```
+---------+----------+  
| info_id |   key    |  
+---------+----------+  
|    1    |  info1   |  
+---------+---------+- 
|    2    |  infor2 |  
+---------+---------+
```

`restaurant_info`

```
+---------+----------+----------+  
| res_id  | info_id  | value    |  
+---------+----------+---------+  
|    1    |   1     |   val    |  
+---------+---------+----------+ 
|    1    |   2     |   val    |  
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: This question is very unclear - it seems as if you're asking several questions as one. Generally, it is best to use many simple tables as opposed to one complicated table, but you should ask a more specific question in order to get a more specific answer.

Comment: With every new field you should perform `ALTER TABLE`. Maybe `EAV` can help you?

Comment: @No'amNewman i just looking the best way to structure this table..i dont want to have a table with bunch of column

Comment: @slier: What specifically is the table supposed to model? If the table holds atomic data for each restaurant, then one large table is ok. If there is repeating data for each restaurant, then you need separate tables with a one to many relationship.

Comment: @No'amNewman its atomic but would have bunch of column..is it ok to have table with lot of column?

Comment: @slier: Yes, it is ok to have a table with many columns, many unfilled. It simply depends on what you are modelling. In your design above, you have a field called 'policy' - this might well need to be a foreign key for a 'policies' table as many restaurants may have the same policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many attributes of the entity and each entity has it's own set of attributes you may use [Entity Attribute Values model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) to store the data.

Comment: In my experience, EVA is fine for storing application wide data for which each field has exactly one value (for example, date of last backup, date of last email read) but otherwise it becomes a pain to extract the data, display it and update it. For example, how would you store a program's SMTP settings, three fields? If they're stored in EVA, you need three queries, one for each field, to retrieve the data, whereas if they're stored in three columns of the same table, they can be extracted in one query.

Comment: @No'amNewman true..i know about eav but generally try to avoid it cause lookup query will become unnecessary complex

Comment: @No`am Newman basically that's what you trade: efficiency for flexibility. Caching is strongly recommended when using eav.